# Matching with number of edges from one side

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_l\}$ be two sets of students. Suppose that each $b_i\in B$ knows at least $m$ students in $A$. Can we always find $m$ **disjoint** pairs $(a_i,b_i)$ such that $a_i$ and $b_i$ knows each other for every pair? (If $A$ knows $B$, then $B$ knows $A$.)

We may be able to apply Hall's marriage theorem, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: We select arbitrary $m$ students from $B: X\subseteq B,\ |X|=m$. Then we apply [Hall's_marriage_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem#Graph_theoretic_formulation) on $X$ and $A$: the theorem's statement holds $\forall W\subseteq X: |W|\le m\le|N_G(W)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Yes, provided that $l \geq m$.
- You don't need Hall's marriage theorem (but you can use it if you wish).
- Pick any student from $B$ and match him with anyone he knows, now you have at least $m-1$ students in $B$ each of whom knows at least $m-1$ students in $A$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$